# EF Core and SQL Server - No Overlapping date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-core, triggers, entity-framework-core

I have been struggling with a situation to which I found no solution as of now.
I have a .net core 3.1 application, using EF Core, that has to track task times for users, these users cannot have overlapping times.

E.g User 1 cannot work from 10am to 11am of a specific day twice, or from 9:30am to 10:20am and also 10:00am to 11:00am, as there are time overlaps.

I am storing the StartDate and EndDate of those tasks, as well as the UserId in my TaskTime table.

I have successfully made verifications in my application layer and a trigger in the database that will stop this from happening, apart from one scenario:

If I have two or more requests coming at the exact same time or within milliseconds of each other, the application checks are useless as both inserts will happen simultaneously, and the database trigger is not stopping the insertion of overlapping records, either the trigger is not executing at all in these scenarios or it is is in fact executing but the rollback seems to not work. The trigger does work in a "slow scenario", for example, a single user adding one record at a time, with time to spare between those requests.

Here is my trigger:

```
create trigger NoOverlappingRanges on TaskTime for insert, update as
begin
    if exists(
        select 1 from TaskTime TT inner join inserted NV on 
        (
            (
                TT.UserId = NV.UserId 
                and 
                TT.StartDate <= NV.EndDate 
                and 
                NV.StartDate <= TT.EndDate
                and
                TT.Id <> NV.Id
            )
        )
    )
    begin
        raiserror('Time ranges should not overlap', 16, 1)
        rollback transaction
    end
end
```

As for the application layer, threads will not know of each other's existence until it's too late, and if there is no parallelism, they are working perfectly.

Thank you very much all for reading and any possible help.

I'll add the relevant app code as well here to be more thorough:

```
public async Task<RequestFeedback> AddTime(int TaskId, Guid UserId, Guid CreatedById, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate, int TimeOffset = 0)
{
    RequestFeedback request = new RequestFeedback();
    try
    {
        EndDate = EndDate.ToUTCData(TimeOffset);
        StartDate = StartDate.ToUTCData(TimeOffset);
        TaskTime time = new TaskTime
        {
            CreatedById = CreatedById,
            Disabled = false,
            EndDate = EndDate,
            RowDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
            StartDate = StartDate,
            TaskId = TaskId,
            UserId = UserId
        };

        ICollection<TaskTime> times = await db.TaskTime.Where(a => a.UserId == UserId && !a.EndDate.HasValue).ToListAsync();
        if (times.Count > 1)
        {
            db.RemoveRange(times);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            request.Success = false;
            request.Title = "There were multiple times being tracked";
            request.Text = "To avoid time conflicts and overlaps, all open tracked times where cancelled";
            return request;
        }

        ICollection<DateTime> Overlaps = await db.TaskTime.Where(a => a.UserId == UserId && a.StartDate <= time.EndDate && time.StartDate <= a.EndDate.Value).OrderBy(a => a).Select(a => a.StartDate).ToListAsync();
        if (Overlaps.Any())
        {
            DateTime Overlap = Overlaps.FirstOrDefault();
            time.EndDate = Overlap.AddSeconds(-1);
            if (time.EndDate < time.StartDate)
            {
                request.Success = false;
                request.Title = "Could not add this time slot with a proper timeframe";
                request.Text = "The given time would either overlap with other time slots or be smaller than 0 seconds.";
            }
            else
            {
                db.Add(time);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                request.Success = true;
                request.Title = "Time slot added successfully";
                request.Text = $"Due to overlaps with other time slots, this end date was set to {time.EndDate.FromUTCData(TimeOffset).DateFormat()} to avoid conflicts.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (time.EndDate < time.StartDate)
            {
                request.Success = false;
                request.Title = "Could not add this time slot with a proper timeframe";
                request.Text = "The given time would be smaller than 0 seconds.";
            }
            else
            {
                db.Add(time);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                request.Success = true;
                request.Title = "Time slot added successfully";
            }
        }
        return request;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        await errorLogService.InsertException(e); throw;
    }
}
```

Once again, thank you for your time

Comment: What do you mean by "the database trigger is failing."?

Comment: Yes by "failing" do you mean it does not appear to function as expected? It may be better to check for `((NV.EndDate between TT.StartDate and TT.EndDate) or (NV.StartDate between TT.StartDate and TT.EndDate))`

Comment: Try using begin transaction

Comment: By the trigger failing I mean it doesn't execute, or if it executes, it doesn't rollback the transaction. If the insert queries are far apart enough, timewise, it works just fine, but somehow, if they are just milliseconds apart, the trigger, well, doesnt trigger, or if it does, things get inserted regardless.

Comment: I would prefer not using a begin transaction statement if possible, since it locks resources, which will have a considerable performance impact when dealing with multiple concurrent requests.

Comment: The first thing to do is log your trigger to a debug table so you know whether it is executing or not. Then you have half as many cases to investigate.